# Multiply each element of a special column of a data frame with the corresponding elements of other columns of the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, multiplication

I have a data frame **df** with four columns; three integer columns and a special column containing a list:

```
df <- data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))

> df
  w x y          z
1 1 3 6       1, 2
2 2 4 7    1, 2, 3
3 3 5 8 1, 2, 3, 4

>class(df$z)
[1] "AsIs"
```

I want to transform each element of the column df["z"] by separately multiplying it with the corresponding element (same row number) of  each of the other columns (df["w"], df["x"], df["y"]) of the same data frame **df**.

I have found the possibility of using Map("*", df$z, df$x), but it can only perform the required multiplication with one other column at a time. My data set is too large to let me  perform the multiplication in such small steps.

```
> Map("*", df$z, df$x) 

[[1]]
[1] 3 6

[[2]]
[1]  4  8 12

[[3]]
[1]  5 10 15 20
```

Can anyone please provide a hint on how to multiply df["z"] with each of the other columns at once while preserving the data frame  structure?

I expect the output to be a data frame **df1**  with column names w,x,y.

```
>df1
w                 x                 y
1 2               3 6               6 12
2 4 6             4 8 12            7 14 21
3 6 9 12          5 10 15 20        8 16 24 32
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output? What do you want the final data frame to be (for this example)?

Comment: May be `lapply(df[1:3], function(x) Map("*", df$z, x))` helps.  But as DanHall mentioned, it is not clear how you wanted the expected output

Comment: akrun's comment gives your desired output. If you want it as a data.frame you can do `as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df[1:3], function(x) Map("*", df$z, x))))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `transmute_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   transmute_at(vars(w, x, y), funs(map2(z, ., `*`)))
#           w             x             y
#1        1, 2          3, 6         6, 12
#2     2, 4, 6      4, 8, 12     7, 14, 21
#3 3, 6, 9, 12 5, 10, 15, 20 8, 16, 24, 32
```

---

Or as @Ryan mentioned if there are more columns and the multiplier `list` column is single, we can use `one_of` within `transmute_at` to select other columns except the 'z'

```
df %>%
    transmute_at(vars(-one_of('z')), funs(map2(z, .,`*`)))
```